# generate constant current from raspberry pi

Tags: constant-current

Hi i'm embedded programmer but not good enough at the electrical side.

Two electrodes are put in a material. I need to drive 50 micro amp current to the electrode and measure the voltage created. (about 5 mv). The old design of the project was using cpu clock to generate 32 khz AC to the electrode. (STM32F405RG chip). 
I want to achieve the same goal with raspberry pi. 
What would be the fastest way to do this for AC current?
please need your help.

Comment: Need more data. What kind of precision do you need? AC you say? Of course some ready-made module would be easiest and therefore fastest, surely that would be true for any application?

Comment: The fact that you want to use a Pi means that the current is not, in fact, constant but is, at a minimum, switched or adjusted under program control. You need to improve your question to explain that aspect. You also need to specify the maximum voltage required in worst case (highest resistance of test material) to ensure that 50 µA can be driven through the load.

Comment: Hi, i should generate 40-50 AC micro amp. can you please advice ready-made modules to use with the raspberry ?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Hi Transistor,  the voltage might be about 5 milivolts. the resistance is about 100 ohms where the electrode is used

Comment: If you don't read the comments carefully and answer each point raised then there is no point in me trying to help you. If you want to alert someone to a comment put an `@` in front of their username.

Comment: @Transistor max voltage required is about 5 mv. the current need to be switched via programming

Comment: Right. As I said in my first comment, you need to put all that information **into your question** so that anyone trying to help you has all the information in one place. Your first comment suggests that you have a tolerance of 20% on your current (40 - 50 µA). Put that in your question too. "*can you please advice ready-made modules to use ...*". No. Product recommendations are not allowed and your question can be closed for asking for one.

Comment: Yes, but now you have introduced another major specification: the current is alternating at 32 kHz. You haven't specified whether this is sinusoidal, square, triangle, etc., and if it is symmetrical about zero. Sorry, I tried but I give up now.

Answer (score 0):

A constant current means just that, a current that does not change. As such there would be no such thing as an AC constant current because by definition an AC signal is forever changing.

Your question is not really possible to answer beyond that because you are asking what we call an X Y type question. You think you know what you need to ask about (X) but in reality what you need is something altogether different (Y). Why don't you start over and describe exactly what you are trying to achieve and then ask for help on a much more pointed issue using terminology fitting to the technology.

Comment: two electrodes are put in a material. i need to drive 50 micro amp current to the electrode and measure the voltage created. (about 5 mv). The old design of the project was using cpu clock to generate 32 khz AC to the electrode. (STM32F405RG chip). I want to achieve the same goal with raspberry pi. thanks much for helping.

Comment: Suppose you have a [digital multimeter that has a "true RMS" AC current scale](https://www.amazon.com/Fluke-FLUKE-87-V-Digital-Multimeter/dp/B0002YFD1K/), and suppose you have an AC power supply that causes that meter to read out a constant value regardless of the load.  Would you not call that power supply a "constant current AC supply?"

Comment: @jameslarge - I think I would call it what it was - "A regulated RMS current supply".